# Iterate over generic list with multiple types

Tags: c#, arraylist, expression, generic-list

I have 3 classes as mentioned below: 
One has the information for removal, rest two classes have actual data. In future there will be more than 30 classes for data

```
public class RemovalInformation<T> where T:class
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Func<T, bool> RemovalCondition { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyReportData
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class ValuationData
{
    public DateTime ValuationDate { get; set; }
}
```

I have a below ArrayList which I want to process

```
        var removals = new ArrayList
        {
            new RemovalInformation<PropertyReportData>
            {
                Data = commercialReportData?.PropertyDetail,
                TagName = nameof(PropertyReportData.PropertyName),
                RemovalCondition = property => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property.PropertyName),
            },
             new RemovalInformation<ValuationData>
            {
                Data = commercialReportData?.ValuationData,
                TagName = nameof(ValuationData.ValuationDate),
                RemovalCondition = property => property.ValuationDate< DateTime.Today,
            }
        };

        ProcessRemovals(removals);
```

Method ProcessRemovals is

```
    private void ProcessRemovals(ArrayList removals)
    {
        foreach (RemovalInformation<PropertyReportData> item in removals)
        {
            var deleteItem = item.RemovalCondition.Invoke(item.Data);
            if (deleteItem)
            {
               //do something here
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem here is, in foreach loop I can access RemovalInformation of only one type. Is there any way to iterate over the list for multiple types of RemovalInformation

Comment: Normally you would make a base class that `PropertyReportData` and `ValuationData` inherit from. If you do not, the base class will be object. And object is definitely the **worst** thing you could even use as a T/part of a T. Below that you would have to check if the current instance is either of the two classes, then cast to it.

Comment: As a second note, you can not use foreach here. foreach uses Enumerators - implicitly created for any array - and those do **not** allow the underlying collection to change. If you wan to modify any collection, foreach is not the path.

Comment: In future there will be more than 30 classes for data, i have mentioned only two classes as of now

Comment: I dont want to remove anything from collection thus foreach is not an issue here

Comment: `foreach (object variableName`

Answer (score 5):

You could use an interface, something like this:

```
public interface IProcessRemoval
{
   bool Execute();
}
```

Just implement it:

```
public class RemovalInformation<T> : IProcessRemoval where T:class
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Func<T, bool> RemovalCondition { get; set; }
    public bool Execute()
    {
        if (RemovalCondition != null) 
        {
            return RemovalCondition(Data);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then iterate:

```
private void ProcessRemovals(ArrayList removals)
{
    foreach (IProcessRemoval item in removals)
    {
        var deleteItem = item.Execute();
        if (deleteItem)
        {
           //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @mtanksl, in order to be able to access to common properties/methods that all the types shares, you will have to define an interface (or abstract class). but for the specific types you can use c# 7(and above) pattern matching:

```
private static void ProcessRemovals(ArrayList removals)
{
    foreach (var r in removals)
    {
         switch(r)
         {
             case RemovalInformation<PropertyReportData> propertyReportData:
                 //do delete with propertyReportData
                 break;
             case RemovalInformation<ValuationData> valuationData:
                 //do delete with valuationData
                 break;
             default:
                 var removalInfo = (IRemovalInformation)r;
                 //do delete with removalInfo that should holds all the common properties and methods
                 break;
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: According to one comment, his plan is up to 30 classes, so a swtich/case will not do it.

Comment: He does not need to cover all the 30 cases. If he has different "shaped" data(different properties and/or methods) that do not share the same pattern with the rest than it does not make sense to group it to the same interface, so he could use pattern matching for those specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use `dynamic` type:

```
private void ProcessRemovals(ArrayList removals)
{
    foreach (dynamic item in removals)
    {
        var deleteItem = item.RemovalCondition.Invoke(item.Data);
        if (deleteItem)
        {
           //do something here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `using System.Linq;` at the start of the file and apply `.OfType<T>()` to filter only a certain type of items in the collection (where `T` is the type you need):

```cs
foreach (RemovalInformation<PropertyReportData> item in removals.OfType<RemovalInformation<PropertyReportData>>())
{    
    //do something here
}
```